# Python Imports - Many Modules not Recognized

Tags: python, import, sqlalchemy, pycharm, interpreter

I am trying to follow a tutorial book called "Data visualization with Python and Javascript" and am running into many issues importing modules used in the book. I have made sure to do "pip install" on as many of the packages used as possible, and have successfully done it for packages such as SQLAlchemy and matplotlib.

However, when I import modules from SQLAlchemy and even dateutil that are used in the tutorial, I receive an import error, "ImportError: No module named {module}"
On the following lines of code:

```
from dateutil import parser
from SQLAlchemy import create_engine
```

This has occurred often enough with different modules that I am beginning to get concerned I can no longer actually follow the tutorial. I had to skip a whole section of how to use SQLAlchemy. 
Furthermore, SQLAlchemy is properly installed:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: sqlalchemy in c:\users\{user}\appdata\local\continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (1.2.15)
```

What obvious thing am I missing here that needs to happen for me to use these packages and modules?

EDIT:

```
python --version
Python 3.7.1
pip --version
pip 18.1 from C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Continuum\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

However, I am using Anaconda for a virtual environment, and PyCharm as my IDE. I have included a screenshot of the projects interpreter for a good measure.[Project Interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5A7zI.png)

Furthermore, I have checked that I have pip installed it on both the root and the environment.[Root](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnbUq.png) [Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIwN0.png)

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling the modules with pip

Comment: It is possible that you have different versions of python. You are installing in one python installation and running the code in another. can you check the pip version and the python version?

Comment: You probably have *multiple Python installations*. Check what `pip` installs for with `pip -V`. Verify that the `python -m site` information matches.

Comment: Also, when importing from SQLAlchemy, the library is all lowercase:
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine`.
The more likely issue is different versions of Python as mentioned above, but maybe this can help.

Comment: You might want to use `pip2` or `pip3` while installing, if you have different versions of Python installed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you have multiple python versions installed.(2.* | 3.*)
You are installing packages in one python version and using another python version.

EDIT:
You can use **pip2 install modulename** for python2
and **pip3 install modulename** for python3

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a way to check the versions of Python as mentioned by @MartijnPieters in the comments above.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response! I honestly do have multiple version of Python installed, however, I only installed Python 2.7 after running into this problem. Both the python (3.7.1) and pip (18.1 for Python 3.7) appear to be the ones I am using. Furthermore, pip2 and pip3 are not recognizable commands? I only get "invalid syntax" when I try to use them. I would love to for a good measure install SQLAlchemy on both versions just in case that helps though

Comment: @C.Dumbluck Try using pip-3.7 install module And also set env variable PATH value to {PYTHON HOME DIRECTORY}\Scripts

Comment: @C.Dumbluck Try using pip-3.7 install module And also set env variable PATH value to {PYTHON HOME DIRECTORY}\Scripts OR check what is pip in Scripts folder and Run from that directory for now

Comment: @infinity The command "pip-3.7 install SQLAlchemy" is invalid syntax, and running the command prompt from my scripts folder just gives me "Requirement already satisfied" when I run "pip install SQLAlchemy"

Comment: @C.Dumbluck I will suggest unistall both the python versions and install fresh Python required version. In your case defaukt python path is for 2.7. i.e the pip your are runnung from is of 2.7 and your 3.7 python is in appdata. You got it in your question. Go to tjat scripts folder and then install modules

Comment: @infinity which image was the one that had Python 2.7? It also only lets me uninstall my miniconda which is in Python 3.7

Comment: Easy way to install mocules from pycharm itself.
On your project interpreter window you can see packages list, click on + symbol and select SQLAchemy and install it. Same way you can install other packages as well. @C.Dumbluck Let me know if it works for you.